# How can I Pass variables to C programm using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, parameters

How can I Pass variables to C program using gcc ??

For example

```
gcc -o server ./server.c --host=localhost --port=1234
```

how to access these variables in my code ?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't at all clear.  If you're talking about command-line arguments, then that's a *runtime* thing, not a *compile-time* thing.

Comment: Look into the `-D` option of `gcc`.

Answer (score 8):

Your question isn't clear; there are at least two things you might be asking about: how to access command line arguments passed to your program when it is run and how to access arguments passed to the compiler when your program is compiled.

Command line arguments:

<kbd>./server --host=localhost --port=1234</kbd>

These are accessed via arguments to `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  for (int i=0; i<argc; ++i) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << '\n';
  }
}
```

[`getopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) is a pretty common way to parse these command line options, though it isn't part of the C or C++ standards.

Compiler arguments:

You can't necessarily access arguments passed to the compiler, but for the arguments you can detect you detect them through changes to the compile environment. For example if the compiler takes an option to enable a language feature then you can detect when that option is passed by detecting if the feature is enabled.

<kbd>gcc -std=c11 main.cpp</kbd>

```
int main() {
  #if 201112L <= __STDC_VERSION__
    printf("compiler was set to C11 mode (or greater).\n");
  #else
    printf("compiler set to pre-C11 mode.\n");
  #endif
}
```

Additionally you can directly define macros in command line arguments to the compiler that the program will be able to access.

<kbd>gcc -DHELLO="WORLD" main.cpp</kbd>

```
int main() {
  #if defined(HELLO)
    printf("%s\n", HELLO);
  #else
    printf("'HELLO' is not defined\n");
  #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define them at compile-time see the `-D` param, if you want to define them at runtime use something like

```
int main(int,char**);
int main(int argsc/*argument count*/, char**argv/*argument vector*/)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<argsc;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",argsv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass variables to your program execution, you can use environment variables. Like this:

```
char* myOption = getenv("MY_OPTION_NAME");
if(!myOption) myOption = "my default value";
//Do whatever you like with the value...
```

And when you call your program, you can set the variables inline by assigning them *before* the program name:

```
MY_OPTION_NAME="foo" ./server
```

You could also set your environment variables once and for all using

```
export MY_OPTION_NAME="foo"
```